What can I use to seal the underside of swollen upper cabinets?
My condo has cabinets from the 80s made from some sort of composite material.  The painted areas are holding up but the bottom of the cabinets above the stove have watermarks and the corners are swelling from the moisture coming from the stove.  Is there some sort of sealant that I can paint the underside of the cabinets?  Or a recommended paint for all that moisture?  It isn't directly above the stove but to the side so I'm not too worried about the food being contaminated but I don't want the problem to get worse and for there to be mold.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Got pics?  Are the cabinet walls made of wood, or chipboard/MDF as well?

Polyurethane (whether clear or pigmented as paint) does a reasonably good job of sealing composite wood products from moisture.
Marine epoxy (i.e. for working on boats) would be the other likely choice, but it's more of a pain to work with.
